# import jquery in vue-cli then some errors show, but it does not affect normal use

Tags: jquery, webpack, vue.js

when i use vue-cli, i import jquery in webpack, and because i use layer.js, so i import jquery in index.html.

#### webpack.base.conf.js

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: "jquery",
    $: "jquery"
  })
],
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>octet</title>
    <script src="./static/js-spark-md5.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/layer/layer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!--<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidebar">-->
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>',
  // components: {template: '<router-view></router-view>'}
})
```

but chrome shows some errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJPjH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i delete `import $ from 'jquery'` in main.js, then this is no error in console